# How to make CnosDB store duplicate data?

Tags: cnosdb

According to CnosDB's [insert syntax](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/query/insert.html#insert), I am trying to write duplicate data points (same timestamp + same tag but different field values in different batch), these data points should have been merged together into one data point. I am using v2.0.1.

See my lab below:

1. Create a table with two tags:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   a BIGINT,
   b BIGINT,
   c BIGINT,
   TAGS(id,name)
);
```

2. Insert a data point with **field "a" ONLY**

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',100);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 100 |  |  |

2. Insert a data point with **field "b" ONLY**

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,b) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',200);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 100 | 200 |  |

3. Insert a data point with **field "a"(same), "b"(same), "c"(new)**

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a,b,c) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',100,200,300);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 100 | 200 | 300 |

4. Insert a data point with **field "a"(different) ONLY**

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',110);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 110 |  |  |

**Expected result:**

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 110 | 200 | 300 |

5. Insert a data point with **field "a"(different), "b"(different), "c"(different)**

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a,b,c) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',120,220,320);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 110 | 220 | 320 |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 120 |  |  |

**Expected result:**

| time | id | name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00.000000000 | 1 |  | 120 | 220 | 320 |

Any workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a v2.0.1 bug.

I tested on v2.2.0, the result is in line with your expectations

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
   a BIGINT,
   b BIGINT,
   c BIGINT,
   TAGS(id,name)
);
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a,b,c) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',100,200,300);
```

Result:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| time                | id | name | a   | b   | c   |
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00 | 1  |      | 100 | 200 | 300 |
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

```sql
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',110);
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| time                | id | name | a   | b   | c   |
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00 | 1  |      | 110 | 200 | 300 |
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

```
INSERT INTO test (TIME, id,a,b,c) VALUES('2023-03-28 16:00:00', '1',120,220,320);
```

Result:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| time                | id | name | a   | b   | c   |
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2023-03-28T16:00:00 | 1  |      | 120 | 220 | 320 |
+---------------------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

The bug has been fixed at https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/pull/761